# xslt transform original xml to new xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am needing to transform an original xml document into another xml document.  In the new xml document I do not know how to pull only certain children and then a few grandchildren and great grandchildren.  Currently I just end up with everything under the TESTRECORD node, which gives me too much extra data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Input XML:

```
<TOP>
  <LEVEL1>
    <TESTRECORD>
      <ENTRYID>267432</ENTRYID>
      <LINEID>254734</LINEID>
      <SEQUENCE>80</SEQUENCE>
      <LINE>
        <ASSETNUM>123456</ASSETNUM>
        <LINEID>254734</LINEID>
        <METERNAME> HCOLOR </METERNAME>
        <ASSET>
          <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
          <ASSETUID>388417</ASSETUID>
          <DESCRIPTION>My Asset Description</DESCRIPTION>
          <SERVICEADDRESS>
            <ADDRESSCODE>5308030000</ADDRESSCODE>
            <STREETADDRESS>1234 Kings Highway</STREETADDRESS>
          </SERVICEADDRESS>
        </ASSET>
        <METER>
          <DESCRIPTION>Hair Color</DESCRIPTION>
          <DOMAINID>HCOLOR</DOMAINID>
          <METERNAME>HCOLOR</METERNAME>
        </METER>
      </LINE>
    </TESTRECORD >
    <TESTRECORD>
      <ENTRYID>555555</ENTRYID>
      <LINEID>222222</LINEID>
      <SEQUENCE>90</SEQUENCE>
      <LINE>
        <ASSETNUM>234567</ASSETNUM>
        <LINEID>222222</LINEID>
        <METERNAME> HCOLOR </METERNAME>
        <ASSET>
          <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
          <ASSETUID>388417</ASSETUID>
          <DESCRIPTION>My New Asset Description</DESCRIPTION>
          <SERVICEADDRESS>
            <ADDRESSCODE>5308030000</ADDRESSCODE>
            <STREETADDRESS>1234 Kings Highway</STREETADDRESS>
          </SERVICEADDRESS>
        </ASSET>
        <METER>
          <DESCRIPTION>Hair Color</DESCRIPTION>
          <DOMAINID>HCOLOR</DOMAINID>
          <METERNAME>HCOLOR</METERNAME>
        </METER>
      </LINE>
    </TESTRECORD >
  </LEVEL1>
</TOP>
```

Desired Output:

```
<jobDocument>
<![CDATA[
<TESTRECORD>
    <ENTRYID>267432</ENTRYID>
    <LINEID>254734</LINEID>
    <SEQUENCE>80</SEQUENCE>
    <ASSETNUM>123456</ASSETNUM>
    <METERNAME>HCOLOR</METERNAME>
    <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
    <ASSETUID>388417</ASSETUID>
    <DESCRIPTION>My Asset Description</DESCRIPTION>
    <STREETADDRESS>1234 Kings Highway</STREETADDRESS>
    <DESCRIPTION>Hair Color</DESCRIPTION>
    <DOMAINID>HCOLOR</DOMAINID>
</TESTRECORD>
<TESTRECORD>
    <ENTRYID>555555</ENTRYID>
    <LINEID>222222</LINEID>
    <SEQUENCE>90</SEQUENCE>
    <ASSETNUM>234567</ASSETNUM>
    <METERNAME>HCOLOR</METERNAME>
    <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
    <ASSETUID>388417</ASSETUID>
    <DESCRIPTION>My New Asset Description</DESCRIPTION>
    <STREETADDRESS>1234 Kings Highway</STREETADDRESS>
    <DESCRIPTION>Hair Color</DESCRIPTION>
    <DOMAINID>HCOLOR</DOMAINID>
</TESTRECORD>
]]>
</jobDocument>
```

Current XSLT that isn't giving the desired results:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform”  
  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<jobDocument>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
             select=" descendant::TESTRECORD" />
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>

</jobDocument>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|comment()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: None of your `TESTRECORD` elements do have any grandchildren. The `NODE2A` etc. elements are on the same level as `NODE2` etc. You just indented them more, but this doesn't have any effect on the XML structure.

Comment: Ok.  Sorry about that.  Let's try this example...  This should give a better idea of what I am trying to do.  Thanks.

Comment: So basically you want to flatten the XML structure below a certain level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a stylesheet to flatten all elements below `<TESTRECORD>`. It does contain some elements you haven't mentioned in your desired outcome, but overall the output comes close to what you expected. Without further criteria it's hard to tell which elements to include and which to exclude. Wrapping the output in a `CDATA` section harms the indentation - but not the structure - of the output. But you should get the idea of the templates.

The `*[count(descendant::*) > 0]` matches all elements with more than 0 children, that is: all elements which have children. The `*[self::TESTRECORD or count(descendant::*) = 0]` matches all elements which are either `TESTRECORD` itself or have zero children. This should copy the `TESTRECORD` element. If you have a different name, you should put it here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <jobDocument>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=" descendant::TESTRECORD" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </jobDocument>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[count(descendant::*) > 0]" mode="copy">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[self::TESTRECORD or count(descendant::*) = 0]" mode="copy">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|comment()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output (approximated):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jobDocument><![CDATA[
    <TESTRECORD>
        <ENTRYID>267432</ENTRYID>
        <LINEID>254734</LINEID>
        <SEQUENCE>80</SEQUENCE>
        <ASSETNUM>123456</ASSETNUM>
        <LINEID>254734</LINEID>
        <METERNAME> HCOLOR </METERNAME>
        <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
        <ASSETUID>388417</ASSETUID>
        <DESCRIPTION>My Asset Description</DESCRIPTION>
        <ADDRESSCODE>5308030000</ADDRESSCODE>
        <STREETADDRESS>1234 Kings Highway</STREETADDRESS>
        <DESCRIPTION>Hair Color</DESCRIPTION>
        <DOMAINID>HCOLOR</DOMAINID>
        <METERNAME>HCOLOR</METERNAME>
    </TESTRECORD>
    <TESTRECORD>
        <ENTRYID>555555</ENTRYID>
        <LINEID>222222</LINEID>
        <SEQUENCE>90</SEQUENCE>
        <ASSETNUM>234567</ASSETNUM>
        <LINEID>222222</LINEID>
        <METERNAME> HCOLOR </METERNAME>
        <ASSETID>388391</ASSETID>
        <ASSETUID>388417</ASSETUID>
        <DESCRIPTION>My New Asset Description</DESCRIPTION>
        <ADDRESSCODE>5308030000</ADDRESSCODE>
        <STREETADDRESS>1234 Kings Highway</STREETADDRESS>
        <DESCRIPTION>Hair Color</DESCRIPTION>
        <DOMAINID>HCOLOR</DOMAINID>
        <METERNAME>HCOLOR</METERNAME>
    </TESTRECORD>]]>
</jobDocument>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have a couple of questions for you about the match criteria.  Can you explain the match="*[count(descendant::*) > 0] and the match="*[self::TESTRECORD or count(descendant::*) = 0]"?  Also, when I apply this to my xml, it is leaving off the <TESTRECORD> element.  Is there a way to get that element copied also?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank You.  This was very helpful.